# Which operator can be used to move cursor to the last non-blank character of the screen line in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I know `g$` can be used to move the cursor to the last character of the screen line, but which operator can be used to move the cursor to the last **non-blank** character of the screen line?

Comment: What do you need this for (so frequently that you want an operator)? Wouldn't `g$b` suffice?

Comment: @IngoKarkat, `g$b` would suffice enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`g_` (g followed by underscore) moves to the last non-blank character of the <del>screen line</del> **text line**. (As pointed out by han pingtian in the comments).

To move to the last non-blank character of the **screen line**, there's no single operator that I could find, but you could combine `g$` with `ge` to achieve this result: use `g$` to go to the last character (blank or non-blank) of the screen line, then if the cursor is on whitespace, use `ge` to move backwards to the last character of the previous word. (And of course, if the character under the cursor is non-blank, just omit the `ge` operator).

If you're trying to write a script, this won't be as helpful as a single dedicated operator, since it requires making a decision about the character under the cursor after the `g$` has completed. But if you're just trying to go to the last non-blank character in visual mode or for interactive editing purposes, the `g$` `ge` combination should suffice for what you need.

Also try substituting `gE` for `ge`, depending on whether you want to skip over punctuation or not. (See `:help word-motions` for the distinction between `e` and `E`: basically, `E` counts ALL non-whitespace characters as word characters, while `e` counts only letters, digits and underscores.)

Comment: Sorry, but looks like `g_` only moves to the last non-blank character of the **whole text line**, not the screen line. I'm wondering if there is an operator can do this ....

Answer (score 0):

**Right of Screen**

`g$`

**Left of Screen**

`g0`

**Top of Screen**

`H`  (*high*)

**Middle of Screen**

`M`

**Bottom of Screen**

`L` (*low*)